# C false error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, compiler-errors

in my project i have three files: PlayBoard.c, Board. c, Board.h, who's relevant parts appear bellow. within PlayBoard i have theBoard which is a pointer to a variable of type struct Board. 
when trying to compile i constantly get a "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type".
moving Board's definition to Board.h helps, but is not possible (it's a homework question), so i need another way.

PlayBoard.c:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
...
int main()
{
BoardP theBoard =//creation of new Board;
 ...
}
```

Board.h:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H


// ------------------------------ includes ------------------------------

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// --------------------------  definitions -------------------------

 /**
  * A pointer to Gomoku table.
 *
 */


typedef struct Board* BoardP;
/**
  * A struct of a Gomoku table.
  */
typedef const struct Board* ConstBoardP;

...

#endif
```

and Board.c:

```
#ifndef BOARD_C
#define BOARD_C

#include "Board.h"


typedef struct Board
{
    char **_board;
    int _cols;
    int _rows;
    bool _turn;
    int _xCounter;
    int _oCounter;
    int _lastx;
    int _lasty;

} Board;

...
#endif
```

Comment: and how do you compile?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `BoardP theBoard` needs a complete type. You don't have one at that point.

Comment: with the compile button. but also with this make command:
PlayBoard: PlayBoard.c Board.h Board.c 
 gcc -DNDEBUG -Wextra -Wall -Wvla -std=c99 PlayBoard.c Board.h Board.c -o PlayBoard

Comment: In general, compiler errors are not "false". It is much more likely that you made a mistake in your code. Which you did.

Comment: Do you really need the `typedef`?

Comment: You don't need include guards in C source files (usually); you don't include C source files, so the protection isn't relevant.  You can only initialize structures where the structure definition is known.  You can do it in `Board.c`; you can't do it in `PlayBoard.c`.  You write a 'create board' function in `Board.c` that returns a pointer to the `Board`, and you store that pointer in the `main()` program — and pass it around to the functions that need it.  And no, it isn't a 'false error'; it is an entirely accurate error.  You can only pass and return pointers to opaque (incomplete) types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler simply using a pointer seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete type of your `struct` is in Board.c, which your PlayBoard.c knows nothing about. All it has is a declaration of a `struct` that you have yet to define (in your Board.h file). Move the definition of the `struct` to within the header file. Barring this, ensure that PlayBoard.c only uses a pointer to `Board` (or a `BoardP`, as per your typedef). You do not need a complete type to declare a pointer. This ensures that any usage of the `struct Board` is confined to Board.c (which I assume is the point of your assignment).

Comment: i cannot move the definition. how can i get  PlayBoard to know Board?

Comment: It is better to use pointers to the structure in all the source files except `Board.c` which actually manipulates the board structure.  See also the duplicate, which goes through this explicitly.